# How to call a REST based API from Databricks using pyspark?

Tags: rest, post, pyspark, get, azure-databricks

I want to call a REST based microservice URL using GET/POST method and display the API response in Databricks using pyspark. Currently I am able to achieve both using python. Here is my python script for POST method:

```
import requests as req
import json

input_data = {'A': 1, 'B': 2}
url = 'http://myurl/v1/post'
input_headers={
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "header1":"value1",
    "header2":"value2,
    "header3":"value3"
}
resp = req.post (url,headers=input_headers, data=json.dumps(input_data))
print(resp.text)
```

And my script for GET method:

```py
import requests as req
url = 'http://myurl/v1/get'
resp= req.get(url)
print(resp.text)
```

But when I'm trying the script for **GET** method in **Databricks**, it is showing Time Out with the following error message:

> ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='myurl', port=40): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/get (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out'))

Can you guys please help me with this?

Comment: This is not your complete code, is it? You’re referencing pyspark and I don’t see you using it. Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and the full stacktrace.

Comment: I see you tagged this question with `azure-databricks`.  Based on the error message it looks like this is most likely a firewall issue.  At least on AWS, the workers can have different firewall rules than the master node (whatever they call those in Azure).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you can get to that URI from the databricks cluster you are using.  Sometimes, it is simply blocked at the physical layer (firewall) and you will not be able to get there.  hence, the time out.